# How can I ensure at compile time that my serialization functions create buffers with the expected size?

Tags: c++, serialization, embedded, static-assert

Currently we use packed structs with bitfields to create our datas

```
struct Data1
{
   uint8_t type;
   uint8_t value;
   bool aBool:1;
   uint8_t threeBits:3;
   uint8_t spare:4;
} __attribute__((packed))
const uint8_t Data1SerializedSize{3};
static_assert(sizeof(Data1) == Data1SerializedSize, "wrong Data1 size");

...

const uint8_t MaxBufferSize{32};

union AllDatas
{
   Data1 data1;
   ...
   uint8_t buffer[MaxBufferSize];
}__attribute__((packed))
static_assert(sizeof(AllDatas) <= MaxBufferSize);
```

It does work because we use the same cpu architecture everywhere and gcc is kind enough to allow us to use members of the AllDatas union that are not the one we last wrote.

```
void send(Serial& serial, const Data1& data)
{
    AllDatas u;
    u.data1 = data;
    serial.write(u.buffer, Data1SerializedSize);
}
```

But:

- It's undefined behavior if we follow the standard specification
- It's heavily platform dependant.
- It's rather messy and ineficient

But it offer the advantage to allow us to check at compile time that our structs have the size that we expect and hence, won't compile if that's not the case (work on 32 bits platform but not on a 64 one for example)

How can I create serialization functions that will ensure that at least, my output buffer has the size expected and that I did not forgot to add some members or on the contrary put one twice for example?

```
std::array<uint8_t, Data1SerializedSize> serialize(const Data1& data)
{
   std::array<uint8_t, Data1SerializedSize> buffer;
   uint8_t head{0};
   buffer[head] = data.type;
   ++head;
   buffer[head] = data.size;
   ++head;
   buffer[head] = (data.aBool & 0x1) 
                | ((data.threeBits << 1) & 0b1110) 
                | ((data.spare << 4) & 0b11110000);
   ++head;
   //static_assert(head == Data1SerializedSize);//won't work and above code looks more error prone
   return buffer;
}
```

The serialization format is clearly defined so I can't switch to a serialization library given that they can't (to my knowledge) be so tightly packed and so won't follow our format from the start.

As a side question, is there a way to avoid the double type declaration of the array (in the return type and in the function body)? I found no way to create a variable of the return type of the function in the function itself?

Comment: The double declaration can be solved with auto return type. If you use C++17 or later the compiler must not copy the returned array (RVO). Instead it will create the array in caller context and lets the function fill it. Maybe you can replace your serialization with protobuf/grpc (if you communicate between two processes)

Comment: @Pepijn Thanks for the advice, I didn't knew that I could just declare a function 
`auto doSomething();`
 in a header, implement it in the source 
`auto doSomething(){return std::array<int,16>{};}`
but then the header loose it's sense given that you can't know the return type of the function without looking at the source... 
I was expecting something that would work the other way around 
`std::array<int,16> doSomething()
{
   std::return_type result;
   return result;
}`
It wasn't much about RVO but more about a way to avoid too much changes if I change the function return type

Comment: From the above, you can make the function `constexpr` and so use in UT: `static_assert(serialize(Data1(..)) == std::array{..});` (You cannot have undefined byte without compilation error like that).

Comment: @BertrandThelen you cannot do that in header. just as your reason goes.

Comment: Given the struct packing, your serialization function would be perfectly fine and well-defined in C. C++ has decided to let such code break for the purpose of making the language less useful. So you are essentially asking why C++ is such a bad choice for embedded systems programming. The answer is probably "far too many PC programmers in the standard committee". C++ has been made useless for hardware-related programming since way back.

Comment: @Lundin, in this case C++ may have made it a bit more difficult event if it does work out of the box with the union trick. But, correct me if I'm wrong, that code was not portable in C++ nor in C. I was not able to compile the same code on the 32bits mcu and on my 64 bits cpu due to the static_asserts meaning that the size of the structs were different even with the packing. Pretty sure it would be the same in C. But I disagree with you regarding C++ as a bad choice for embedded programming C++ can offer more security in terms of memory management if you use the right tools.

Comment: @BertrandThelen The only things that are implementation-defined in C here, is the non-standard packing option itself. And of course endianess and bitfields etc but none of that is related to well-defined type punning of C and undefined type punning in C++. Using bitfields is a bad mistake in either language. As for "memory management" you shouldn't be using heap allocation in embedded systems to begin with. All C++ can "help out" with there is to create subtle heap allocations that you didn't see coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get something that can check at compile time not only that the size is right but that my serialization and deserialization functions work as expected as well

serializer.h

```
struct Data1Serializer
{
   static const uint8_t size{3};
   constexpr std::array<uint8_t, size> serialize(const Data1& data);
   constexpr Data1 deserialize(const std::array<uint8_t, size>& buffer);
}
```

serializer.cpp

```
constexpr auto
Data1Serializer::serialize(const Data1& data)
-> std::array<uint8_t, size>
{
   std::array<uint8_t, size> buffer;
   uint8_t head{0};
   buffer[head] = data.type;
   ++head;
   buffer[head] = data.value;
   ++head;
   buffer[head] = (data.aBool & 1)
            | ((data.threeBits >> 1) & 0b111)
            | ((data.spare >> 4) & 0b1111));
   ++head;
   assert(head == size);
   return buffer;
}

constexpr auto
Dat1Serializer::deserialize(const std::array<uint8_t, size>& buffer)
-> Data1
{
   Data1 data;
   data.type = buffer[0];
   data.value = buffer[1];
   data.aBool = buffer[2] & 1;
   data.threeBits = (buffer[2] >> 1) & 0b111;
   data.spare = (buffer[2] >> 4) & 0b1111;
   return data;
}

consteval bool checkData1()
{
   Data1 data{3,2,true,5,0};
   Data1Serializer serializer;
   const auto& result = serializer.deserialize(serializer.serialize(data));
   
   return (data.type == result.type)
       && (data.value == result.value)
       && (data.aBool == result.aBool)
       && (data.threeBits == result.threeBits)
       && (data.spare == result.spare);
}

static_assert(checkData1() == true, "Data1 serialization or deserialization failure");
```

With the out of bound checks of the array made at compile time, the assert to ensure that we filled the entire buffer and the comparison made in checkData1() I can be confident that my serialization and deserialization functions work.

I think that I will just move all that to unit tests to avoid the compilation time overhead and all the constexpr that are required for every function involved in the consteval check but it's nice to know that it's possible.

Comment: With c++20, `bool operator==(const Data1&) const = default;`, `checkData1` can even be simplified.